# How to call selector from switch only when change to state ON in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need call a function with selector when change switch, but only when I set switch to On state:

```
 cell.switchMy.addTarget(self, action: "openView", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

  func openView(){
    var cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell5") as CustomCell
    if(cell.switchMy.on == true){
        println("ON")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueUnl", sender: self)
    }
}
```

If I use this code, always call the function, but I 'm controlling if the switch state is ON... How can this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (nearly) the right way to do this. You can't have a method be called only when the switch state is `on`.
But you don't need to retrieve the cell from the `openView` method. The sender will be passed by the caller:

```
cell.switchMy.addTarget(self, action: "openView:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

func openView(sender: UISwitch){
    if(sender.on) {
        println("ON")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueUnl", sender: self)
    }
}
```

*Be careful: the selector used in `addTarget` needs to be changed from `openView` to `openView:`*